# Is it possible to call into javascript from a background thread running in a cordova android plugin

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I have a Cordova application using a native plugin on Android (other platforms to come).

My plugin is loaded at application start (`<param name="onload" value="true" />` in plugin.xml) and my native code does some work in the `initialize` method (overloaded from the `CordovaPlugin` class).

Essentially, the work I do in the `initialize` method then causes an event to be generated at a later time, and I need to deliver this event to the javascript API.

Is there any way I can asynchronously call into the javascript from the native side of the plugin, without first having called into the plugin from the javascript side? (a call from JS->Java would give me a CallbackContext which I could use to issue the callback, I assume).

I found this 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/NativeToJsMessageQueue.java
but I don't know how to use it and I cannot find any documentation - I'm not even sure if it works or is intended for public use.

Can I use `webview.loadUrl("javascript: ... ");` to call in to the javascript side, or will this disrupt or interfere with the cordova framework running in JS (if any)?

Is there a recommended way of acomplishing this, and is it supported across multiple platforms (or are the concepts applicable to other platforms?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am using a workaround - I have the user call through to my plugin (JS->java) and in doing so they provide the callback function they are registering.

In the Java side I then store the `CallbackContext` for use later.
One important thing, it is very important that when you use `CallbackContext.sendPluginResult`, the `PluginResult` that you pass has to be marked with the `PluginResult.setKeepCallback(true)` method, otherwise the first call back to the CallbackContext will cause the context to become invalid for future calls.

I haven't noticed any threading issues with this and I am not sure (but hopeful) that it is applicable to the other platforms.